# Does an async callback function throw an event when it completes?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webservice-client, system.reactive

I found a great page on making efficient asynchronous calls to web services with minimum effort here:

http://www.jaylee.org/post/2010/06/22/WP7Dev-Using-the-WebClient-with-Reactive-Extensions-for-Effective-Asynchronous-Downloads.aspx

What I'm confused about is where do I place the code that I want executed after the response is received from the server? Does the system raise an event when this happens? Simply placing the code after the call to the asyncdownload does not give this functionality.

---

I should've been more clear; I have this code in my project:

```
    private void SearchBarcode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        var o = Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(wc, "DownloadStringCompleted")

                          // Let's make sure that we’re on the thread pool
                          .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)

                          // When the event fires, just select the string and make
                          // an IObservable<string> instead
                          .Select(newString => ProcessString(newString.EventArgs.Result))

                          // Now go back to the UI Thread
                          .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher)

                          // Subscribe to the observable, and set the label text
                          .Subscribe(s => parserInput = s);

        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid=appidhere&query=barcodenumber&sources=web"));
    }
```

I don't see where I can place the DownloadCompleted event call. SearchBarcode is an onclick handler for an image; where does control go after SearchBarcode is executed? I want to manipulate the value of parserInput and call another xaml page passing these values. I've tried adding a void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) but it doesn't get called, obviously. What am I missing here? :(

Comment: Whould you please explain more about what you want exactly? The code you put in the "DownloadCompleted" event handler will be run after the download completed. So what you want more than it? Or what is the problem about that?

Comment: For reference, events are raised. Errors are thrown.

Comment: Guys, I've edited my question to be more specific. Thanks for looking :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this logic at the end of the callback.

In the sample you linked that's what he's doing with the Dispatcher in DownloadCompleted.

This is a sample project I wrote demonstrating use of HttpWebRequest. At the end of ResponseCallback you will see...

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { httpWebRequestTextBlock.Text = contents; });
```

... to update the UI.

Feel free to ript this code and use your URL.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)

Comment: No worries, I've added a working sample project which you can plug your url/ui update logic into. Looks like you've picked up an Rx (Reactive Extensiosn) example though now.. was that part of your initial requirements?

Comment: The reason I went with Rx is because it accomplishes the same thing as HttpWebRequest (does not block UI thread). I went through your code and it seems very straightforward. while my project does not *require* Rx, I would like to not change things because they work :P The problem is, I still can't get the callback function to work. I've tried void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) and all its variants but still no luck :(

Comment: In the post your looking at, he's updating his UI with .Subscribe(s => myLabel.Text = s, e => myLabel.Text = "Error ! " + e.Message);

Comment: Yes, I understood that line. I just wanted to know if it is possible to replace the myLabel.Text = s bit with a function call.

Comment: @Freakishly - Don't think of Rx as "not blocking the UI thread", think of it as managing asynchrony.

Comment: I managed to get my app working with httpwebrequest, thanks for a great msdn post, mick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put you're code in the `DownloadCompleted` method, which is called with the result of your download. Be aware that any code will execute on the main thread. If you have heavy processing to do, I suggest `HTTPWebRequest`

Comment: Hiya Thomas, I'm not familiar with HTTPWebRequest and its usage in this context. Could I get a link, please?

Comment: It will work the same way as Webclient, but in the callback you'll have some more code to access the UI thread. doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx example of use : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8

Comment: Thanks... this is a nice page with a good clean example :) I will try adding a DownloadCompleted method and get it to work before marking your answer as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for everything Thomas, I converted my code to use httpwebrequest successfully, using Mick's example :)